# Screen capture without main window

Tags: c#, wpf, screen-capture

I will like to take a screen capture without a window. I currently hide my main window take a screen shot of the desktop and then make my main window visible again. Will it be possible to achive the same functionality without having to hide my window?

If you are curios on why I am trying to achieve that functionality then look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004802/create-vista-glass-effect-on-wpf-with-custom-color) that I am trying to solve.

Comment: It's possible but you are digging yourself a deeper and deeper hole.  Just type "wpf glass" in a google query and take the first hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) class to convert your Visual to a bitmap.

Comment: How to get the Visual object containing screen without MainWindow. Please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

Tried something like Jing or SnagIt?  SnagIt seems to be the most fully featured of the screen capture tools.  So, if anything has this, it would be SnagIt.

Comment: Yeah but I have to get the image with code... I need to do this with C#